# Django how to set or update data from filtered data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

my code like this

```
def change_order_status(request):
    user = request.user
    teacher = Teacher.object.get(id = user.teacher.id)
    today = datetime.now()   
    today = today + timedelta(minutes=30)
    today = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    test = []
    if request.method=="POST":
        teacher_time = Student_Time.object.filter(teacher_id = teacher.id, paid=0, status=2)
        for tt in teacher_time:
            if tt.order_date < today:
                **tt.update(paid=1)**
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('teacherStatistic'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('teacherStatistic'))
```

i want set or update that **tt.paid** to 1(default 0). How can i do it using **for loop** with **if**.
**tt.paid = 1** or **tt.update(paid = 1)** both are not working pls help me;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it and save it

```py
def change_order_status(request):
    user = request.user
    teacher = Teacher.object.get(id = user.teacher.id)
    today = datetime.now()   
    today = today + timedelta(minutes=30)
    today = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    test = []
    if request.method=="POST":
        teacher_time = Student_Time.object.filter(teacher_id = teacher.id, paid=0, status=2)
        for tt in teacher_time:
            if tt.order_date < today:
                tt.paid = 1
                tt.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('teacherStatistic'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('teacherStatistic'))
```

**Make sure the if statement is actually evaluated the way you wanted**

Answer (score 1):

you should save after changing the  tt.paid value

```
for tt in teacher_time:
    if tt.order_date < today:
        tt.paid = 1 
        tt.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about...

`teacher_time.filter(order_date__lt=today).update(paid=1)`
and you drop the loop and the individual saves